# Print the last element in a dictionary in a set

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to select the last element from the following output.

```
print(result)
[('ABC', 880, {0: 'A', 1: 'P', 2: 'O', 3: 'T', 4: 'S'}),
('CDE', 120, {0: 'S', 1: 'E', 2: 'N'}),
('EFG', 240, {0: 'G', 1: 'R'})]
```

Desired output:

```
[S,N,R]
```

Comment: Please show actual code. btw there are no sets in what you've shown so far

Comment: What is `result` without a print? Your objects are not sets but dictionaries (sets are unordered)

Comment: where's pandas here

Comment: I get an output like this for my program using for loop. I need to select the last element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a list of tuples and each tuple has three elements of which the last is a dictionary then you could do this:

```
list_ = [
    ('ABC', 880, {0: 'A', 1: 'P', 2: 'O', 3: 'T', 4: 'S'}),
    ('CDE', 120, {0: 'S', 1: 'E', 2: 'N'}),
    ('EFG', 240, {0: 'G', 1: 'R'})
]

for _, _, d in list_:
    print(list(d.values())[-1])
```

**Output:**

```
S
N
R
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this?

```
alist = [
    ('ABC', 880, {0: 'A', 1: 'P', 2: 'O', 3: 'T', 4: 'S'}),
    ('CDE', 120, {0: 'S', 1: 'E', 2: 'N'}),
    ('EFG', 240, {0: 'G', 1: 'R'})
]

print([adict[max(adict)] for _, _, adict in alist])
```

**Output:**

```
['S', 'N', 'R']
```

Comment: if i want  output: ['S', 'N', 'R'] in this format what i need to change?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a list `l` of tuples as input:

```
out = [list(t[-1].values())[-1] for t in l]
```

output: `['S', 'N', 'R']`

To print:

```
print(*out, sep='\n')
```

output:

```
S
N
R
```

Comment: if i want the first and second element also on the output. How to change this code